# Common super class for similar XML files

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-ws

I am currently developing an applications that reads XML files from an API. The API does not provide schema information.

I've created my java beans according to the following article: http://duckranger.com/2011/06/jaxb-without-a-schema/

This works, but I have a problem to create a proper common super class.

The XML files of the API come in two flavors - one when there is only one item in the response, and one when there is a collection of items in the response. For the sake of discussion, focusing on only the case where there is one item in the response should be enough. The responses always have the following form:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<xxxapi version="2">
  <currentTime>2010-10-05 20:28:55</currentTime>
  <result>
    <property_a>...</property_a>
    <property_b>...</property_b>
  </result>
  <cachedUntil>2010-10-05 20:33:55</cachedUntil>
</eveapi>
```

The important thing is that, depending on the request, only porperty_a, property_b etc. change. The remainder of the naswer stays the same.

Now I've created the following bean to unmarshal that data (shortened, setters are not included here):

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement(name="xxxapi")
public class XXXAPICall {       

    private Date currentTime;
    private Date cachedUntil;

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class)
    @XmlElement(/*name="currentTime",*/ required = true)
    public Date getCurrentTime () {
        return currentTime;
    }       

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class)
    @XmlElement(/*name="cachedUntil",*/ required = true)
    public Date getCachedUntil () {
        return cachedUntil;
    }
}
```

Now, this works fine and does what it should do. But I have trouble to create a generic solution that doesn involve much copy and paste.

I've created another class, FooBean:

```
XmlRootElement(name="result")
public class FooBean {

    private String property_a, property_b;

    @XmlElement(name="property_a", required = true)
    public String getProperty_a(){
        return property_a;
    }
}
```

And so on. Now I tried to combine that somehow:

```
public class FooBeanCall extends XXXAPICall {

    public FooBean fooBean; 

    @XmlElement(name="result")
    public FooBean getFooBean () {
        return fooBean;
    }

    // setter omitted

}
```

But this doesn't work:

```
MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/xml; charset=utf-8, type=class FooBeanCall, genericType=class FooBeanCall
```

So, how to do what I want to do? Basically, I have dozens of API calls with different results, but the outer structure is always the same. I don't want to c&p the whole code over from each request to each other one, but would like to have the common elelemnts processed ba a common super class. I'd appreciate any hint on how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured one way to do this out myself. You don't set the `@XMLRootElement`-Annotation on the abstract super class, but instead on every concrete sub class (in this example, not on `XXXAPICall` but on `FooBeanCall`).